# Group By object within a nested list linq

Tags: c#, linq

What i am trying to do is i have sales order object which contains

```
sales order header
and list of order lines
```

within the order lines i have the actual order line, product information object and stock information object:

```
public class SalesOrder
{
  public Header SalesHeader { get; set; }
  public List<OrderLineProductInfo> OrderLines { get; set; }
}

public class OrderLineProductInfo
{
  public Line salesOrderLine { get; set; }
  public Info ProductInfo { get; set; }
  public Stock ProductStock { get; set; }
}
```

so i can get a list of SalesOrder Objects so example sales order index 0

has 2 lines the ProductStockObject within one of these lines has Preferred Supplier of abc and the other line has Preferred Supplier 123

i want to be able to group on the Preferred Supplier property

```
var separatePreferredSuppliers =
     (from b in x.OrderLines
                 .GroupBy(g => g.ProductStock.PreferredSupplier ) 
                   select ...
     ).ToList();
```

not quite sure what comes next what needs to be selected? a new list of SalesOrder?

I want it so that it gives two instances of the sales order but split in 2 one for each preferred supplier

Comment: This question looks to be what you're after, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I think I get what you mean

```
from line in x.OrderLines
group line by line.ProductStock.PreferredSupplier into grouped
select new SalesOrder
{
     OrderLines = grouped.ToList()
}
```

though I'm not sure how you populate your `SalesHeader`

Answer (score 0):

easy when you know what the groupby function ruturns -- you want the key and the list:

```
.Select( (g) => new { supplier = g.Key, prodlist = g.ToList()}
```